# Web API - Load Testing

Tags: performance, load, asp.net-web-api, load-testing

I have a WebAPI method for the POST operation. I wanted to do load testing with the same using Visual Studio 2013. Per my knowledge, what I did is, added a load test and called the unittest method written to the above POST webapi method and added some performance counters to it. Is the the only option or do we have any other efficient way to do the same.

Thanks,
Srikanth

Comment: did you ever find a good solution for this?